# US citizen traveling to Jordan - what documents are needed?

Tags: visas, usa, us-citizens, jordan

I am a US citizen traveling to Jordan for the first time. I will be flying into the airport in Amman-Jordan. I have a valid passport and I have read about getting a visa upon arrival. What other documents do I need? As well do I need special documents to obtain the visa at the airport??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The government website doesn’t say anything about any documents apart from a passport valid for 6 months.

I guess you should also have a good travel history and no criminal record in Jordan or anywhere in fact.

You should also have:

- Proof of return
- Adequate health insurance
- Adequate finds
- Intended address(es)

> A passport with a validity of at least six months and a visa are required. Jordan issues single-entry visas to U.S. citizens upon arrival at Amman’s Queen Alia International Airport, Sheikh Hussein crossing at the Israeli border, and the three border crossings with Saudi Arabia (Umari, Mudawara and Durra).

- https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Jordan.html

Note the visa will cost around $56.